# Delete script is not working as intended in my template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs, http-delete

I have an html page that is supposed to show a user account's blogs (so there is an Account Cluster, a Blog Cluster, and the `account` has a `blogs` field that stores the relevant blogs in an array) and give the user the option to delete the blog from the front end.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var x =0; x<account.blogs.length; x++){ %>
        
            <li><a href= "/blogs/<%=account._id%>/<%=account.blogs[x]._id%>"> <%=account.blogs[x].title %></a></li>
                <li><a class="delete<%=x.toString()%>" data-doc="<%=account._id+'/'+account.blogs[x]._id%>"> delete</a> </li>
                <script>
                    
            
                    const trashcan = document.querySelector('a.delete<%=x.toString()%>')
                    trashcan.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{const endpoint = `/my-blogs/${trashcan.dataset.doc}`;
                fetch(endpoint,{method:'DELETE'
            })
            .then((response)=>response.json())
            .then((data)=> window.location.href=data.redirect)
            .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
                })
                
                </script>
      
        <% } %>
    </ul>
```

So, each blog has a link to its own page and an option to delete it by clicking the `delete` text under it.  I have two problems:

1. Only the first delete script works.  I cannot click the other `delete` text to do anything.  I have checked on cloud.mongodb.com and verified that the blog is gone from the Blog cluster.
2. The blog is not removed from the `account.blogs` array.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that since these are all objects, the pointer to the Blog object in the array should become `null`.  Below is the relevant delete method:

```
app.delete('/my-blogs/:idacc/:idblg',(req,res)=>{

                    console.log("In delete my-blogs/id ")
                    const idblg = req.params.idblg;
                    const idacc = req.params.idacc;
                    Account.findById(idacc).then((resultacc)=>{
                    Blog.findByIdAndDelete(idblg)
                    .then(resultblg=>{
                        res.json({redirect: `/my-blogs/${idacc}`})
                    })})
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log(err)
                    })

                })
```

Also, can someone recommend some good testing and debugging tools for me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is client-side JavaScript code (server-side code seems to work fine, because it's deleting the blog). You're assigning the same variable multiple times, which fails.

A quick and dirty solution would be to add loop index to it:

```
 const trashcan<%=x%> = document.querySelector('a.delete<%=x.toString()%>')
            trashcan<%=x%>.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{const endpoint = `/my-blogs/${trashcan<%=x%>.dataset.doc}`;
        fetch(endpoint,{method:'DELETE'
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((data)=> window.location.href=data.redirect)
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
        })
```

But that's really ugly.

It might be better to add `onclick` handler to every `a` tag, and move that code into a single function, which would take blog data as an argument, and by that remove extra attribute from `a` tag (also, you need to add `event.preventDefault` to prevent browser from following that link).

So, try this:

```
<script>
function deleteBlog(event, doc) {
  event.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete', doc);
    const endpoint = `/my-blogs/${doc}`;
    fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => window.location.href = data.redirect)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}
</script>


    <ul>
        <% for(var x =0; x<account.blogs.length; x++){ %>
            
            <li><a href="/blogs/<%=account._id%>/<%=account.blogs[x]._id%>"> <%=account.blogs[x].title %></a></li>

            <li><a class="delete<%=x.toString()%>" onclick="deleteBlog(event,<%=account._id+'/'+account.blogs[x]._id%>)"> delete</a> </li>

            <% } %>
    </ul>
```